# Solving error 00226 to publish a joined table from ArcGIS Pro to Online

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, attribute-joins

I've created a layer where I've appended population data to a set of polygons (neighbourhoods of a city) by using a join. I want to share this layer on a web app, but I get an error message when attempting to publish to ArcGIS Online - saying that 'in-memory joins are not supported'.

How can I convert this layer to a format where this is possible?

I have tried exporting the features, however when I do this the population column in the output loses the values and I get a set of 0s. The same happens if I use the 'copy features' tool.

Comment: What format is your population data in?

Comment: Just numeric double

Comment: Did this help any? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/sharing/analyzer-error-messages/00226-in-memory-joins-and-relates-are-not-supported.htm

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating your problem. First, I joined a table to a polygon feature class. Then I tried publishing it as a web layer. I got the same 00226 error. So, following [this ESRI help doc](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000025311) I was able to publish. My workflow:

1. joined a table to a polygon feature class
2. right clicked the feature class> Data> Export Features> Output Location (make sure it's in a geodatabase)

[image: img1]

3. Share> Web Layer> Publish Web Layer

Alternatively, you could try this: https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/analyze/join-features.htm